# CSS style doesnt apply to some elements

Tags: html, css, angular

I was trying a template css style for elements. Using angular material.

But the some element of my CSS doesn't apply. If i insert it directly into html page, it does work as usual. I use chrome for testing. I am trying to align text to flex-start, but something is going wrong. I think that take style from index.html - .mat-grid-tile .mat-figure . I need to align all text (md-card-title, md-card-subtitle, md-card-content) to the flex-start.Then i run snippet all works, but in my project it dont worked.
Can some answer what i am doing wrong?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <title>AdsBoard</title>
   <base href='./'>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loading-app">
    <img src="assets/image/loading.gif"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
md-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

md-card-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-card-subtitle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-card-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-grid-tile {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}


h1 {
    color: #673ab7;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 58px;
    line-height: 54px;
    text-shadow: 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

a {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #673ab7;
}

.price-content{
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #00bd0d;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>All goods</h1>
<md-card>
    <md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
        <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="3">
            <img md-card-image src='./assets/image/001.jpeg' alt='picture'>
        </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
            <md-card-title><a [routerLink]='["/goods"]'>Audi A8</a></md-card-title>
        </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
            <md-card-subtitle>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description</md-card-subtitle>
        </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
            <md-card-content class="price-content">50000 $</md-card-content>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
</md-card>
```

UPDATE: If i use just /deep/ .mat-figure it works, but just for all elements on page, i need just for 3 of them. Example down dont working

```
/deep/ .mat-figure .mat-card-title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start !important;
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to add `!important` to your custom styles to override default Angular Material's styles, for example (fake example):

```
md-grid-tile {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

And some parts of DOM are generating dynamically via Angular Material: you didn't write them in HTML template, but Angular Material put them to the DOM. In this case, you need to use `/deep/` (has analogues) in CSS, for example (fake example):

```
/deep/ .md-popup {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: I think /deep/ is not working on Angular 4.3.0. Or i do something wrong.

Comment: @GerzogTheBat, I use 4.2.6 and it works fine, not sure about 4.3.0, but I think, it should work too.